# GPS tracking system for find each other in a close area - Android

Tags: java, android, gps

I am developing an android application which should has the capability of finding each other in a close area. I've posted a question which describes all the requirements. Please look at ([Android : GPS tracking system for find each other in a close area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321620/android-gps-tracking-system-for-find-each-other-in-a-close-area))

I am using a service but I don't know how to run this service periodically (once in 15 mins or so ). And also I have no clear idea about how to send the location of devices to the server and how to fetch locations of friend's device.

Here is my attempt.

My xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="stopNewService"
    android:text="Stop Service" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:onClick="startNewService"
    android:text="Start Service" />
```

This is my **MyService.java** class

```
package com.example.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here...
    Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
```

And here is my **MainActivity.java** class

```
package com.example.service;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button bStart, bStop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

// Start the service
public void startNewService(View view) {

    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

// Stop the service
public void stopNewService(View view) {

    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        startNewService(v);

        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        stopNewService(v);

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

}
```

I've added the service into manifest file.

```
<service android:name=".MyService"></service>
```

I would be much thankful if anyone please be so kind enough to help me to clarify this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

For the service, you can use an [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) or a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

As for the fetching/sending of data, you have to have a server located somewhere (not sure what you are not getting with the server part, but you can ask for/give more information afterwards). My best bet with the server is creating a web service (WCF Rest) and communicating with it via AsyncTask (JSON) from any Android device.